# "An error occurred" - always when trying to view YouTube video

Tags: troubleshooting

for some months now, every attempt to view a youtube video causes the "an error occurred" screen shown in capture1.jpg. Left mouse click in that window provokes the dialog shown in capture2.jpg. Clicking OK in that dialog takes you back to step 1. You must go through this process twice, and then the video will play. I would like to go thru this process zero (!) times. Any help appreciated.
Windows 7 home prem SP1
Tor Browser 7.5.6

Thank you. [image: capture1]  [image: capture2]

Answer (score 1):

I tried mobile onion browser and it doesn't play YouTube, invalid responses received. I would guess that YouTube have some tor block in place.